# ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS option for Index...how does it work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

So if you have an index (Index1) with the ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS options set to ON on Table1.  Would it be possible that data on Table2 will not be accessible because Table1 & Table2 have data on the same page(s) that are being locked while Index1 is being used?

Answer (score 1):

No, pages are not shared across tables

There are mix extents...

> Mixed extents are shared by up to eight objects. Each of the eight
>   pages in the extent can be owned by a different object.

This however doesn't matter for this

Comment: Thx for the clarification!  Can you give me an example of when mixed extents are present/used?  What kind of objects share mixed extents if not tables and indices?

Comment: if an object is smaller than 8 pages it might share the extent with another object that is smaller than 8 pages..that way when you have a bunch of small tables you are not stuck with extents that are 50% empty